# How can I configure my Next.js app to use custom error pages for 404 and 500 errors?

Tags: next.js, custom-error-pages

By default, Next.js comes with its own error pages that are used to handle HTTP errors such as 404 (Not Found) and 500 (Internal Server Error). However, we can customize these error pages to match the look and feel of your application. The question is How?

Comment: [next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-500-page) - please do your own research before asking here and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom 404 and 500 error pages.

For 404 error page, create a new file in the pages directory with the name `404.js` and you can create your own custom 404 page content there

For example

```js
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}
```

You can do the same for 500 internal server error page. Just create a file called `500.js` in the pages directory, and occupy it with such custom content.

You can even make use of `getStaticProps` in these pages if you are fetching some content and these errors pop up.

For more information on error pages in nextjs, check out [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page)

Comment: It's All right But the thing I want is a common error file to be created and it will be rendered on all possible errors. Please have a look I just want to handle stuff like this.

function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{statusCode}</h1>
      <p>Oops! Something went wrong.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Check out the advanced error configuration in the link attached https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page